# Installing SharePoint 2010 enterprise into an RODC site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation

I've not been able to see much on the internet about this but seeing if someone has actually attempted it. I've got a situation where I need to install 2010 enterprise into an RODC site. This is a school based setup and I do not have an option of having any accounts 'replicating directory changes' or have it even communicate with a writeable DC as that will not be allowed since the SOE prevents such a thing. I can foresee that I will pretty much have no luck getting the UPSA running and generally have to accept that My Sites will be out of the picture. However I hope that I can basically get it working in some capacity.

Can anyone speak from experience on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone elses future reference I can confirm that the SP2010 Ent deployment into an RODC only site went far smoother than I expected. The only hurdle is that the user profile import job will present a hassle as the communication to a writeable DC is required for this. Thankfully I didn't really need the features the UPSA offered so this didn't really present a problem.